# Two dimensional array that stores 10 questions and 10 answers

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, methods, multidimensional-array

I have written a program that uses a two dimensional array that stores 10 questions and 10 answers.

The program prompts the user with a state, and the user has to answer it with the right capital of that state, then the program tells the user if the answer was correct or not. At the end the program outputs the number of correct answers.

My code worked when in for loop I specified the location like this:

```
for(int x=0;x<a[0][0].length();++x)
```

but if I do it that way I will have to write 10 for loops, is there anyway I can do it in 1 for loop? Also, why am I getting `Exception`(s)

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException: 10
>   (lines 13 and 21)
> ```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HW11 
{
  static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    String a[][]=new String [2][10];
    a[0][0]="NJ";
    a[1][0]="Trenton";
    question(a);
  }

  public static void question(String a[][]) 
  {
    int score=0;
    String what;
    for(int x=0;x<a[10].length;++x)
    {
      System.out.println("What is the capital of "+a[x]+"?");
      what=in.nextLine();
      if(what.equalsIgnoreCase(a[1][0])) {
        System.out.print("That is correct");
        score=score+1;
      } else {
        System.out.print("That is not correct");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My code worked when in for loop I specified the location like this: for(int x=0;x<a[0][0].length();++x)                                 but if I do it that way I will have to write 10 for loops, is there anyway I can do it in 1 for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array has only two possible indexes for the first position. And only from 0-9 on the second. I think your for loop was meant to look like

```
for(int x=0;x<a[0].length;++x) // <-- 0,9
```

Finally, I think this

```
System.out.println("What is the capital of "+a[x]+"?");
what=in.nextLine();
if(what.equalsIgnoreCase(a[1][0]))
```

was meant to look something like,

```
System.out.println("What is the capital of "+a[0][x]+"?");
what=in.nextLine();
if(what.equalsIgnoreCase(a[1][x]))
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply very much, it worked except that when it asks the question second time it says "That is correct What is the capital of null?" But hopefully it is only because I did not include more States yet. I will reply in a little bit when I include more questions and answers. Hopefully you will still be on the website if I will run in to more trouble.

Comment: This is a great website, but it sucks that whenever I seek help my question gets down voted as if I did something wrong. I clearly stated the question, my error and my code without any useless info. Its like as if people get paid here to help others.

Comment: @Alex I've edited your question to try and help you understand why I believe your question was being so heavily downvoted (I did not downvote); 1) Your indentation was horrible, that bothers a lot people. In the future paste your code here, highlight it and then press ctrl-k (to auto add 4 spaces). 2) You added a comment to clarify instead of editing your question. You should give a summary, a description, and a bit of prose before your code. And don't just copy the homework question statement as your introduction. It should be irrelevant, you've done the work. Tell us what isn't working,

Comment: @Alex and this is a voluntary site unless they work for StackExchange (which is generally disclosed on their profile, and they have moderator diamonds) - but again, it's irrelevant. People vote on the quality of your communication. Your comments here are well written, try and make your questions well written too and you'll start getting upvotes.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate someone actually explaining why my post was badly edited AND helping me a great deal with the code instead of just down voting it.